# AngularJs requires page refresh after API call

Tags: angularjs, model-binding

I am writing an angularjs app. The requirement is to display the user's data once the user logs in. So when an user successfully logs in, he/she is routed to the next view. My application is working fine upto this point. Now as the next view loads I need to display the existing records of the user. However at this point I see a blank page, I can clearly see in the console that the data is being returned but it is not binding. I have used $scope.$watch, $scope.$apply, even tried to call scope on the UI element but they all result in digest already in progress. What should I do? The page loads if I do a refresh

```
 (function () {
"use strict";

angular.module("app-newslist")
    .controller("newsController", newsController);

function newsController($http,$q,newsService,$scope,$timeout)
{

    var vm = this;
    $scope.$watch(vm);
    vm.news = [];
    vm.GetTopNews = function () {
        console.log("Inside GetTopNews");
        newsService.GetNewsList().
        then(function (response)
        {
            angular.copy(response.data, vm.news);
        }, function () {
            alert("COULD NOT RETRIEVE NEWS LIST");
        });
    };
    var el = angular.element($('#HidNews'));
    //el.$scope().$apply();
    //el.scope().$apply();
    var scpe = el.scope();
    scpe.$apply(vm.GetTopNews());
    //scpe.$apply();
}
```

})();

Thanks for reading

Comment: How are you displaying `vm.news` in the UI?

Answer (score 1):

you don't show how you're binding this in your template.. I tried to recreate to give you a good idea.

I think the problem is the way you're handling your promise from your `newsService`. Try looking at [$q Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443361/how-to-use-q-service-in-angular-js-for-login). `vm.news` is being updated by a function outside of angular. use $scope.$apply to force refresh.

the [original fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/TechNinja/dug8dao2/) and [a working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/TechNinja/dug8dao2/1/)

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var app = angular.module("app-newslist", [])
    .controller("newsController", newsController)
    .service("newsService", newsService);

  newsController.$inject = ['$http', 'newsService', '$scope']
  newsService.$inject = ['$timeout']

  angular.bootstrap(document, [app.name]);

  function newsController($http, newsService, $scope) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.news = $scope.news = [];
    vm.service = newsService;

    console.warn(newsService)

    vm.message = "Angular is Working!";

    vm.GetTopNews = function() {
      console.log("Inside GetTopNews");

      newsService.GetNewsList().
      then(function(response) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
          $scope.news.length > 0 ? $scope.news.length = 0 : null;
          response.data.forEach(function(n) {
            $scope.news.push(n)
          });

          console.log("VM", vm);
        })

      }, function() {
        alert("COULD NOT RETRIEVE NEWS LIST");
      });
    };

  }

  function newsService($timeout) {
    return {
      GetNewsList: function() {
        return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
          $timeout(function() {
            console.log("Waited 2 seconds: Returning");
            res({
              data: ["This should do the trick!"]
            });
          }, 2000);
        })
      }
    }
  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>


<body>


  <div class="main">
    <div class="body" ng-controller="newsController as vm">
      Testing: {{ vm.message }}
      <br>{{ vm.news }}
      <br>{{ vm }}
      <br>
      <button class="getTopNewsBtn" ng-click="vm.GetTopNews()">Get News</button>
      <br>
      <ul class="getTopNews">
        <li class="news-item" ng-repeat="news in vm.news track by $index">
          {{ news | json }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I can easily bind with button click but I want the binding on page load. I can see data being fetched in the console log. I doubt the data is fetched after the UI is loaded and angular digest has completed. Once I refresh the page the binding works.    View                                                                        <table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
                <tr ng-repeat="info in vm.news">
                    <td>{{info.title}}</td>
                    <td>{{info.highlights}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

Comment: instead of binding to an ng-click, just call the function in your controller. `function newsController($http, newsService, $scope) { /* Previous Code */ GetTopNews();}` .. this will do the same as pressing btn and when refreshing page, will always load results first thing.